# Code to create download link which expire using nodejs or express [frontend and backend]

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm new here. I just started using node.js - express.js
I want to add download link which expire after certain time to my website.
I'm struggling to code this since a week.
Anyone who knows please provide the code [frontend and backend], it will be a huge help.

Comment: So where is your code?

Answer (score 3):

Check this simple implementation:

You store the information of the download in a file. The filename is the download session id. The file content is the real path of the file to be downloaded.

Use these three functions to manage the life cycle of the download sessions:

```
    /* Gets the download file path related to a download sid */
      function getDownloadFilePath(downloadSid, callback) {
    // Get the download session file name
       var dlSessionFileName = path.join(DL_SESSION_FOLDER, downloadSid + 
        '.download');

    // Check if the download session exists
    if (!fs.existsSync(dlSessionFileName)) return callback(new 
    Error('Download does not exist'));

    // Get the file path
    fs.readFile(dlSessionFileName, function(err, data) {
      if (err) return callback(err);

    // Return the file path
     callback(null, data);
    });
   }

   /* Deletes a download session */
    function deleteDownload(downloadSid, callback) {
     // Get the download session file name
    var dlSessionFileName = path.join(DL_SESSION_FOLDER, downloadSid + '.download');

  // Check if the download session exists
  if (!fs.existsSync(dlSessionFileName)) return callback(new Error('Download does not exist'));

  // Delete the download session
  fs.unlink(dlSessionFileName, function(err) {
    if (err) return callback(err);

    // Return success (no error)
    callback();
  });
}
```

Use createDownload() to create download sessions wherever you need to. It returns the download sid, then you can use it to build your download URL like: http://your.server.com/download?sid=.

Finally you can add a simple handler to your /download route:

```
app.get('/download', function(req, res, next) {
  // Get the download sid
  var downloadSid = req.query.sid;

  // Get the download file path
  getDownloadFilePath(downloadSid, function(err, path) {
    if (err) return res.end('Error');

    // Read and send the file here...

    // Finally, delete the download session to invalidate the link
    deleteDownload(downloadSid, function(err) {
      // ...
    });
  });
});
```

With this method, you don't have to create/move/delete big download files, which could cause slow responses and unnecessary resource consumption.

Comment: how to create download link in html for this code

Comment: @DEADPOOL U just mentioned back-end. So he answered it in backend only. Else you can edit your question to back-end as well as front-end

Comment: @DEADPOOL try `<a href="your-file-name.txt" download="">Download file</a>`

Comment: @deadpool Being unfriendly and rude is not welcomed in Stack Overflow. This question is downvoted and closed because you do not read the site guidelines and asked a question that isnt suitable for Stack Overflow. Please please please the [ask] section of Stack Overflow. You have to create a [mre] and show us the problems you are facing while attempting this. Please also note that Stack Overflow isnt a free code writing service or a tutorial provider. Goodluck